# C#: Why does my string return object type and not the value it contains?

Tags: c#, string, list, types, foreach

I am looping through a `List`, and trying to instantiate one of the properties as a string, but it returns the type:

> {Namespace.Collection}

If I put a break-point, I can see that it holds the value I need.

How can I make it return the value and not the type?

```
foreach (var PropertyName in ListName) {
    string n = PropertyName.ToString();
}
```

UPDATE (added more of my code, as well as an attempt of implementing suggested solutions):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows) {

//PaidTrips is my ObservableCollection instance.
//PaidTrip is my holder class which it has been bound to.

                        PaidTrips.Add(new PaidTrip {

                            LicenseHolderID = dr[0].ToString(),
                            // adding more properties
                        });

                        List<PaidTrip> theseTrips = PaidTrips
                            .GroupBy(p => new { p.LicenseHolderID })
                            .Select(g => g.First())
                            .ToList();
                       
                        foreach (PaidTrip PaidTrips in theseTrips) {

                            foreach (var LicenseHolderID in PaidTrips.GetType().GetProperties()) {

                                string n = LicenseHolderID.GetValue(PaidTrips).ToString();

// code to create PDF
}
```

`gfx.DrawString(n, new XFont("Arial", 40, XFontStyle.Bold), ridelGreen, new XPoint(40, 350));`

This is what I do with `string n`. But when the PDF is created, the string output is `System.Action`1[System.Action]`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the type of `ListName` how is it defined ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#the-default-objecttostring-method

Comment: `string n = PropertyName.GetType().ToString();` What is the value of `n` in that instance?

Comment: @TheGeneral the list is like this:
`List<ClassName> listName = ListName
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.PropertyName})
    .Select(g => g.First()
    .ToList();`

Where `ListName` is an `ObservableCollection`

Comment: @mjwills the value of `n` is still `{Namespace.ListName}` . "ListName" is the name of the `ObservableCollection` I based the `List` on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the Property Types in your custom class, after looping through the list. First we need an additional loop - to loop through each ClassName Object in ListName list.

```
            foreach (ClassName myObj in ListName)
            {
                foreach (var PropertyName in myObj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    string n = PropertyName.GetValue(myObj).ToString();
                }
            }
```

Then we need to loop the actual properties of the current loop ClassName object.

Then you pass the argument .GetValue (as you are now looping through the properties - the actual properties assigned, not the definition of properties).

After, you still need to specify what object you want the value of. So by passing myObj, you are specifying the ClassName->Property of the current loop of ListName.

EDIT:

```
            List<Notes> myNotesNow = new List<Notes>();

            myNotesNow.Add(new Notes
            {
                note1 = "Valuye"
                // adding more properties
            });

            List<Notes> theseTrips = myNotesNow;

            foreach (Notes PaidTrips in theseTrips)
            {

                foreach (var myVariable in PaidTrips.GetType().GetProperties())
                {

                    string n = myVariable.GetValue(PaidTrips).ToString();

                    string forBreakPoint = "";
                    // code to create PDF
                }

            }
```

Comment: Hello @Novorfay, thanks!  I appreciate that, that is interesting. I might be doing something wrong, that gives me the output of `System.Action1[System.Action]` when I try to use the string. `myObj` which you reference, that'd be the name of my `ObservableCollection` right? 
I am just putting the code to create PDFs right into that last `foreach`.

Comment: Can you show me the complete usage? Maybe edit your OP so we can all see it - Where you've declared the variables, and then how you are trying to consume the value? It's difficult to completely understand like this. @OleM

Comment: I understand, I will update my question. Thanks!

Comment: @OleM Edited my answer - but the code I passed you works for me - I changed out your class and put my mine (since I don't have access to your PaidClass - no idea what variables it has) - but when I set my breakPoint on string **forBreakPoint** I can verify that within the loop, string **n** in fact has the correct value.

Change `dr[0].ToString()`  to a fixed value for testing purposes - are you sure that you are getting a value from that?

Comment: You are right - I've gone through all the code with break-points, and the correct value is brought along through it all, lol. But the PDF still ends up with the `{System.Action1[System.Action]` as text, and just before now, it ended up with a decimal value from one of the other columns, without me changing anything. When I passed the string to a `MessageBox.Show` it did pass the correct value. Confused..
If you don't have any other ideas, I'm marking your solution as accepted, and creating a new question specific to my PDF method, I think...

Answer (score 1):

For your question - I guess that `ListName` is not of type `string` and so you get the expected behavior (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#the-default-objecttostring-method)

In that case you can override the `ToString()` function of that object to return whatever you need like this:

```
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return "whatever you want including class properties";
   }
```

On another note, the general approach to variable naming in C# is camelCase and starts with lower case so I suggest to name your variables `propertName` instead of `PropertyName` and `listName` instead of `ListName`.

Moreover - naming variables for how they are implemented (`ListName`) is not a best practice as it binds them together, not allowing flexibility in case implementation changes (that comment is true only if it makes sense, as I dont see all the code)

Cheers

Comment: Hello, and thanks! Struggling to implement this. I am trying to get the string value within a method, and so I am not sure how to access the `override ToString()` method. Is it possible to achieve the same functionality from within my method? And also, would you give an example for what you wrote in your return line. Would I just return `propertyName`?

Comment: HI! some more data is needed in order to help. what exactly is the object `PropertyName` ? is it an instantiation of a class created by you or other party?

Comment: Thanks for following up. `PropertyName` is a property of type string in my holder class `MyClass`, bound to an `ObservableCollection`, which I've in turn made a list of. It's filled with string values from a SQL database column.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `PropertyName` is a list of strings (`List<string>`)? that would explain why the string printed is `{Namespace.Collection}`

Comment: Hm, yes, that makes sense. It is indeed a list of strings, and I am trying (with a foreach-loop), to get the specific instance of that string. (I am essentially building invoices, and need the string value of each `PropertyName` so that I can make one invoice per instance of `PropertyName` ..

Comment: so wouldnt iterating the `PropertyName` (which is a list of strings) give you all the strings? meaning - use an inner loop like `PropertyName.ForEach(name => DoWhatever(name))` or something similar